# Condition based API url in JSON

Tags: json, api, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using a JSON to make a call to some APIs. My sample JSON is something like :

```
{
  "call": [
    {
      "url": "https://URL",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "httpHeaders": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "httpContentType": "application/json"
    }
  ]
}
```

My requirement is to select the URL based on some condition. For example, if **employeeType='Employee'**
the url in the above JSON should be https://URL1 and if **employeeType='Contractor'** then the url should be https://URL2.

Is this possible to achieve? and how?

Comment: It's not clear how you're handling the whole situation. Can't you just do an if before generating the json and then generate it with the right link? Or if you already have the json, you can still change it before sending it.

Comment: Please update the question with code showing how are you creating this json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. You can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and write to the file.

Here is the code.

```
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsson);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (dynamic item in json["call"])
            {
                if (item.employeeType=="Contractor")
                {
                    json["call"][count].url = "https://URL2";
                    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
                    File.WriteAllText("YOUR JSON DATA PATH", output);
                    count++;
                }
                else if (item.employeeType == "Employee")
                {
                    json["call"][count].url = "https://URL1";
                    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
                    File.WriteAllText("YOUR JSON DATA PATH", output);
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

And here is the `json` file that I edited.

```
{
  "call": [
    {
      "url": "https://URL2",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "httpHeaders": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "httpContentType": "application/json",
      "employeeType": "Contractor"//I added employeeType if you want to fetch data from here
    },
    {
      "url": "https://URL1",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "httpHeaders": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "httpContentType": "application/json",
      "employeeType": "Employee"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://URL1",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "httpHeaders": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "httpContentType": "application/json",
      "employeeType": "Employee"
    }
  ]
}
```